# How to stretch table cell according to BG image?

Tags: html, image, tablecell

I want to stretch my table cell, to show whole background image. Right now it only stretches according to cell's content.

How do I make table to be same size as background image from the very begining?

Answer (score 0):

Use css to set width and height of cell, for example we have the following cell

```
<td class="plus"  id="slideinit" title="more options">
  &nbsp;
  </td>
```

it has the css

```
<style type="text/css">
.plus
{    
background:url(images/plus.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left:2px;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
</style>
```

I used the above code to fit the width and height of an empty cell to display a PLUS icon as background image. Although I haven't uploaded the image that is being used in this example, you can get an idea from this css. you can share your code if the above code doesn't work.

Comment: But in this example you're selecting  width and height manually. I don't want that. I want my browser to do that job. I'd also like to set background in HTML rather then CSS.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without using CSS, there is a somewhat similar scenario in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176094/stretch-image-to-fit-in-td)